# Query for the lack of requests in specific points in time

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an Elasticsearch/kibana stack that stores every request the application receives. It stores gereneral information about the request (RequestTimestamp, IP, Headers, HttpStatus, Route etc), and there's at least some requests per minute.

**I would like to know if there's some way to query Kibana/Elastic to know the points in time that the application didn't receive any request for, let's say, 3 minutes.**

I know it can be done programmatically, but it needs to be purely done with querys (so I can show it on the Dashboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do [date histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html).

You could specify 3m interval and query for a specified day.
So you would get `24*60/3 = 480` values for each day.

You could plot it on the chart and see the gaps.
If you are an expert ES user you could try filtering the aggregations using [bucket selector pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) or create a moving average using [moving average aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-movavg-aggregation.html).